# PointLight not working after Three.js update

Tags: typescript, three.js

After updating Three from 0.100 to 0.156.1, the point light has stopped working.

[This is what the scene looked like before the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEwfZ.png)

[This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1DxN.png)

This is the code:

```
const HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_ON = true;
const HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_SKY_COLOR = 0xFFFFFF;
const HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_GROUND_COLOR = 0xFFFFFF;
const HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_INTENSITY = 0.6;
const POINT_LIGHT_ON = true;
const POINT_LIGHT_COLOR = 0xFFFFFF;
const POINT_LIGHT_INTENSITY = .7;
const POINT_LIGHT_DISTANCE = 0;

private _addLights() {
    if (HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_ON) {
        this.hemiLightHandle = new THREE.HemisphereLight(
            HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_SKY_COLOR,
            HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_GROUND_COLOR,
            HEMISPHERE_LIGHT_INTENSITY
        )
        this.scene.add( this.hemiLightHandle);
    }
    if (POINT_LIGHT_ON) {
        this.pointLightHandle = new THREE.PointLight(
            POINT_LIGHT_COLOR,
            POINT_LIGHT_INTENSITY,
            POINT_LIGHT_DISTANCE
        );
        this.pointLightHandle.position.set(0, 60, 30);
        this.scene.add(this.pointLightHandle);
    }
}
```

The hemisphere light is working. I can see differences in the scene if I change any of the light's constants. On the older version of the code, I can turn off the point light and get the same effect I'm seeing now, so I'm confident I figured out at least part of the problem. With the updated Three, I've tried...

- Changing all of the point light's constants
- Changing the position, including setting it to (0, 0, 0).
- Adding decay to the constructor and setting it to 1.

The result has been the same each time.

I've tried comparing the point light object between the two different versions of the code, but the only differences I'm noticing are the additions of isCamera, isPerspectiveCamera, and isObject3D.

Any ideas on what else I should try or check?

Gonna also mention that I'm not that experienced with Three or knowledgeable on the terminology. I might need a little extra handholding with explanations and suggestions.

Comment: three.js r155 made significant changes to the lighting — see https://discourse.threejs.org/t/updates-to-lighting-in-three-js-r155/53733 for details on what has changed, and what you can do to migrate your code.

Comment: Looks like I just needed to increase the intensity a lot more. Thanks!